# Download HTML5 Attribute not working? - PHP

Tags: php, android, html, hash, download

I am trying to make a download page in PHP as a project... I went OTT and encrypted the file names but I cannot change them back on download using the download HTML5 attribute (Tested with androids firefox and android chrome), here's my code currently:

```
<?php
  
  $file = $_GET['file'];

  $extension = strripos($file, '.');
  $extension = substr($file, $extension +1);

  $filename = rtrim($file, "." . $extension);
 
  $hash_1 = hash("SHA512", "djf84jdS4i3jd83jnKusIFOd82a93" . $_GET['file']);
  $hash_2 = hash("MD5", "kfic93Jdf9SjdSjfiDkdiUw" . $hash_1 . "UHFe83jfYsufi3Jsjfm");
  $hash = substr($hash_2, 0, 10);

  $file = "/get/" . $hash . "." . $extension;
?>

<a href="<?php echo $file; ?>" download="<?php echo $filename . "." .echo $extension; ?>"><img src="download.png"/></a>
```

Live example: http://mc-omegacraft.tk/download.php?file=index.php

---

#### Resolved

Error with android chrome.
Basically firefox is better as the android browser: P

Comment: Thanks, Josh... I don't know why it went weird on me though.

Comment: You need to use the code format option looks like brackets `{}`

Comment: Yeah, I tried the conventional [code][/code]

Comment: I added a live example page so yeah...

Comment: I don't really know any php, but as a start, is your code even being run? Also what is the android tag for? Seems unnecessary.

Comment: Just incase it's do to with the android browsers (I'm using android)

Comment: And yes it is being run, take a look at my example page

Comment: You are missing the period in the extension. The download name only shows indexphp

Comment: It's concatenated in the href code

Comment: Oh yeah, sorry... thanks lemme try that

Comment: Still not working and neither are the {}

Comment: @JoshMein The {} aren't working...

Comment: You don't use brackets. You are supposed to use the button that looks like brackets in the editor.

Comment: Im using the android app... there isnt any

Comment: You can add 4 spaces before every line of code. It does the same thiing.